# Python (Selenium) - Invalid selector when using Xpath

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I want to ask my python to click a link from a web page and I have tried below 3 ways to specify an Xpath to a Span element in my python code:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ChartUnitsHistory_ranges']/span[text()='1y']").click()
```

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='graphControls']/span/1y")
```

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='graphControls']/span[text()='1y']").click()
```

but all of these failed with the same error message:

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: The
>   specified selector is invalid.

Updated Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "02042020.py", line 31, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='ChartUnitsHistory_ranges']/a[text()='1y']").click() File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\Web_Scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)   File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\Web_Scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {   File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\Web_Scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Users\username\PycharmProjects\Web_Scraping\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: The specified selector is invalid.
```

I need help on coming up with the correct Xpath for the '1y' option.

HTML Source Code:

```
<div class="graphControls">
            <a href="javascript:jsChartUnitsHistory.getOptions().shiftRange(100, true)">&lt;&lt;</a>&nbsp;
            <a href="javascript:jsChartUnitsHistory.getOptions().shiftRange(33, true)">&lt;</a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="javascript:jsChartUnitsHistory.getOptions().shiftRange(33, false)">&gt;</a>&nbsp;
            <a href="javascript:jsChartUnitsHistory.getOptions().shiftRange(100, false)">&gt;&gt;</a>&nbsp;
            <a href="javascript:jsChartUnitsHistory.getOptions().updateRange(0,'now')">&gt;|</a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <a href="javascript:jsChartUnitsHistory.getOptions().zoom(50);">[ + ]</a>
            <a href="javascript:jsChartUnitsHistory.getOptions().zoom(200);">[ - ]</a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <span id="ChartUnitsHistory_ranges" style="">
                    <a href="javascript:jsChartUnitsHistory.getOptions().updateRange(1,'year')">1y</a>
            <a href="javascript:jsChartUnitsHistory.getOptions().updateRange(3,'month')">3m</a>
            <a href="javascript:jsChartUnitsHistory.getOptions().updateRange(1,'month')">1m</a>
            <a href="javascript:jsChartUnitsHistory.getOptions().updateRange(2,'week')">2w</a>
            <a href="javascript:jsChartUnitsHistory.getOptions().updateRange(1,'week')">1w</a>
            <a href="javascript:jsChartUnitsHistory.getOptions().updateRange(3,'day')">3d</a>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </span>
            <a href="#" id="ChartUnitsHistory_embiggen" onclick="EnlargeFlotChart( 'ChartUnitsHistory', jsChartUnitsHistory, 1100, 312 ); return false">enhance</a>
            <a href="#" id="ChartUnitsHistory_restore" style="display:none;" onclick="RestoreFlotChart( 'ChartUnitsHistory', jsChartUnitsHistory, 700, 160 );;return false">unenhance</a>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

The layout of these elements looks like this on the web page:

<< 
            <
              
            > 
            >> 
            >|
                
            [ + ]
            [ - ]
              
        
                    1y
            3m
            1m
            2w
            1w
            3d
               
        
            enhance
            unenhance

---

Please also see the attached screenshot of the web page: 
[Screenshot of the webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iWPq.png)

Please let me know if information provided is enough or not. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text "1y" is in `<a>` tag, the parent element with `id='ChartUnitsHistory_ranges'` is `<span>`

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='ChartUnitsHistory_ranges']/a[text()='1y']").click()
```

`"//div[@class='graphControls']/span/1y"` didn't work because "1y" is treated like a tag here.

`"//a[@class='graphControls']/span[text()='1y']"` didn't work because `class='graphControls'` is in `<div>` tag and the element is no a direct child, `/` is for direct child, `//` for any descendant.

You can also use `css_selector` for that

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ChartUnitsHistory_ranges > [href$="(1,\'year\')"]').click()
```

Comment: I used the xpath you provided but the same error still occurred. I also added driver.implicitly_wait(5) before the xpath line of code. Any suggestions? Thanks :)

Comment: @an1que You are getting `Invalid selector exception`? this is kind of wired. Actually all the `xpath` you used are valid, just didn't match. Can you post the full error message?

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@id='ChartUnitsHistory_ranges']/a[text()='1y']").click() File "", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File ", line 976, in find_element return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "", line 321, in execute self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "", line 242, in check_response raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: The specified selector is invalid.

Comment: Please see the updated error message from the original post for better viewing.

Comment: @an1que Can you share the link?

Comment: You won't be able to access cause it's an internally used web page :(

Comment: @an1que Are you able to use the xpath in dev tools?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207378/discussion-between-guy-and-an1que).

Answer (score 1):

The desired element is an [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element, so to click on the element ideally you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "1y"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.graphControls span#ChartUnitsHistory_ranges a[href*='year']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='graphControls']//span[@id='ChartUnitsHistory_ranges']//a[contains(@href, 'year')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports:

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Chrome, you can click `F12` to switch to the Developer Mode and locate the HTML element. Then right click the element to copy:

- css selector
- Xpath or full Xpath
- JS path
- Styles

In your case, you need to copy the `Xpath`. 
This would be a quick way to get the Xpath.

Comment: "Then right-click the element to copy:" Can be written as "you can follow these tips to navigate to the Xpath".